# Optimization techniques for three.js

Tags: three.js

I want to embed a 3D model in a web page, but after embedding the model with three.js, the material, lighting, and shadow effects of the model are not good. Is there any way to optimize it?

I tried some methods from the official documentation of three.js.

Comment: https://threejs-journey.com/lessons/performance-tips